# setwallpaper scrollable in android 4

Tags: java, android, eclipse, wallpaper

Good morning
I have a code that works right to set wallpapers which was downloaded from net at a size of 1024 x 768 in jpg
when I set a wallpaper, this is distributed to all homescreens but from android 4+ they are not scrollable, putting a part of the image fixed for all homescreens
I would like to solve the problem so I hope you could help me

greetings and sorry for me english

```
//path is a String with image's url
public int setWallpaper(String path) {          
    int width, height;
    Bitmap dbm, bm;         
    bm = null;
    dbm = null; 
    InputStream is = null;

    WallpaperManager wpm = wallpaperManager.getInstance(this);              

    //all images are 1024x 768 
    //to scale bitmap the widht have to be 1.33 bigger than screen's height
    if((wpm != null) && (dis != null)){ 
        height = dis.getHeight();
        width = (int) (height * 1.33);              

        try {           
            URLConnection conn = new URL(path).openConnection();                
            conn.connect();             
            is = conn.getInputStream();                 

            if (is != null) {                   
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(is));                    
                dbm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, width, height, false);                  
                wpm.setBitmap(dbm); 

            }else {
                return 2;
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {                 
            e.printStackTrace();                
        } catch (IOException e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();                
        } finally {             
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }           
        if(bm != null){
            bm.recycle();
        }
        if(dbm != null){
            dbm.recycle();  
        }           
    }else {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are no longer scrollable on android 4, however, to avoid them being zoomed in, you can do the following:

```
// get screen dimensions
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

wpm.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
wpm.setBitmap(dbm);
```

By using suggestDesiredDimensions you specify the size of the wallpaper.

From the developer reference:

> public void suggestDesiredDimensions (int minimumWidth, int
>   minimumHeight)
>
> Since: API Level 5 For use only by the current home application, to
>   specify the size of wallpaper it would like to use. This allows such
>   applications to have a virtual wallpaper that is larger than the
>   physical screen, matching the size of their workspace.
>
> Note developers, who don't seem to be reading this. This is for home
>   screens to tell what size wallpaper they would like. Nobody else
>   should be calling this! Certainly not other non-home-screen apps that
>   change the wallpaper. Those apps are supposed to retrieve the
>   suggested size so they can construct a wallpaper that matches it.

Remember you will also need to request the SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS permission on your manifest by doing:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to put the wallpaper shared among all homescreens
Your response does not reflect any changes, the wallpaper continues fix with the same part of image to all homescreens